# underscore.js groupBy sub-array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have some data

```
var data = [ 
    {type: "A", role:[1,2]},
    {type: "B", role:[2]},
    {type: "C", role:[2,3]},
    {type: "D", role:[3]} 
];
```

I'm trying to sortBy 'role' using underscore.js

```
var groups = _(data).groupBy(function(el){
    return el.role
  }
);
```

Is there a easy way to get reapeated data like this

```
1: {
    {type:"A" ...}
},
2: {
   {type:"A" ...},
   {type:"B" ...},
... etc
```

not like this http://jsbin.com/IzEwUkim/2/edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, as usual, do it by hand with [`_.reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce), something like this:

```
var groups = _(data).reduce(function(memo, o) {
    _(o.role).each(function(i) {
        memo[i] = memo[i] || [ ];
        memo[i].push(o);
    });
    return memo;
}, { });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/HDE3c/

You could use a plain `for` loop instead of `_.each` to iterate over the roles of course.

`_.groupBy` isn't going to work here as the function/key is always a single value so I think you're stuck unwrapping the `role` arrays by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for underscore, but here's native js:

```
var map = {};
data.forEach(function(obj){
  obj.role.forEach(function(roleVal){
    (map[roleVal] = map[roleVal] || []).push(obj);
  });
});
console.log(map);
```

Comment: You could also use the native [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) if you wanted to skip the separate `var map = { }`. Nothing wrong with native solutions.